# Apache htaccess remove trailing slash on internal redirect with parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a subdirectory called /al on my website, which I wish to redirect to the main page, with a language setting.

So I have the following rule:

```
Redirect permanent /al /?lang=en
```

But after verification with cURL, I am getting sent to `/?lang=en/` instead. How can I remove the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` for regex capability:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/al/?$ /?lang=en
```